# Scala covariance with lower bound

Tags: scala

I am looking at scala in action book and it has this code

```
sealed abstract class Maybe[+A] {
    def isEmpty: Boolean
    def get: A
    def getOrElse[B >: A](default: B): B = {
        if(isEmpty) default else get
    }
}
    final case class Just[A](value: A) extends Maybe[A] {
    def isEmpty = false
    def get = value
}
case object Nil extends Maybe[scala.Nothing] {
    def isEmpty = true
    def get = throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.get")
}
```

If the signature of getOrElse is defined as
    def getOrElse(default: A): A =
It doesnt compile.

The author states 
"The lower bound B >: A declares that the type parameter B is constrained to some super type of type A"

Yet I seem to be able to do this and it works

```
val j1 = Just(1)                                  
val l1 = j1.getOrElse("fdsf")  //l1  : Any = 1
```

Is String a super type of Int? What am i not understanding as to why this works? Its like its falling back to argument 1 being type A being of type Any (which it is) rather than type Int.

Answer (score 3):

In Scala you cannot have covariant types in method parameters.

This is because allowing covariant types in method parameters breaks type safety.

In order to have a covariant type you must use a bounded type:

```
getOrElse[B >: A](default: B): B
```

This says find some type, `B`, such that it is a superclass of `A` and that becomes the method return type.

In your case `A` is `Int` and you pass in a `String`. The only type `B` which is a superclass of both `Int` and `String` is `Any`.

In this case `B` becomes `Any` so the method returns `Any`.